# Unexpected error about no return type in friend declaration in C++

Tags: c++, function, class, namespaces, friend

I am trying to compile the following code (simplified from actual use) using g++:

```
namespace A {
    class B;
}

A::B operator+(A::B a, A::B b);

namespace A {
    class B {
    private:
        int i;
    public:
        B() : i(0) {}
        B(int j) : i(j) {}

        friend B ::operator+(B a, B b);
    };
}

A::B operator+(A::B a, A::B b) {
    return A::B(a.i + b.i);
}

int main() {
    A::B a(1), b(2);
    A::B c = a+b;
    return 0;
}
```

To the best of my understanding, the friend declaration in class B is correct, and the :: global scope declaration is needed otherwise the compiler assumes that A::operator+(B a, B b) is meant.

However, on compiling this, gcc gives the error message

```
ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘operator+’ with no type
```

I have no idea how to fix this. The error messages after it give the impression that gcc is ignoring the space between B and :: in that line, instead interpreting this as a friend declaration of a member function of B. How can I tell it what I want?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'Stack' with no type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8275205/iso-c-forbids-declaration-of-stack-with-no-type)

Comment: generally what I would do while declaring a friend function is inside the class I will only have declaration of it like friend int operator+() and outside the class, I could define it like int B::operator+() .. don't know if that will work in ur case or not

Comment: @SIMEL: Unrelated for me: there is no `const& T` here.

Comment: Don't know why your code doesn't work (as moving `operator+` in another namespace works), but you can use [that](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1967de35b1bcfa38) which is more idiomatic anyway.

Comment: The compiler is, indeed, ignoring the space between `B` and `::`. That's because the space is irrelevant: you could replace all those mentions of `A::B` with `A :: B` without changing the meaning. You're allowed to put spaces between the class name and the scope qualifier. That's not why you're getting this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the friend operator inside the class definition the following way

```
friend B (::operator+) (B a, B b);
```

or like

```
friend B (::operator+(B a, B b));
```

Otherwise the compiler considers it like a member function of the class declared without an explicit return type (int is implied)

```
friend B::operator+(B a, B b);
```

Though it would be much better to declare it like

```
friend B (::operator +)( const B &a, const B &b);
```

Comment: I don't agree with the suggestion for 

friend B (::operator +)( const B &a, const B &b); 

using that one would need to also define the rvalue variant, and it depends on the type whether it is a performance benefit in practice.

But the brackets suggestion was the key, thanks for that one.

Comment: @davidv1992 There is no need to declare the operator for rvalues. It is enough to declare it for constant references. Otherwise there are redundant calls of the constructor and destructor.

Answer (score 1):

`::` is being treated as a scope resolution operator applied to `B`: `friend B::operator+(B a, B b);` So to make it work you should put `friend` keyword after returned type name:

```
B friend ::operator+(B a, B b);
```

[check working code online](http://ideone.com/LrWnqK)